# Showing taxonomies with terms that are attached to custom post

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries

So, I have to show the taxonomies that are present on a custom post, with their terms.

I have some taxonomies (around 10) and all of them have a few terms. Eacho post can have any number of taxonomies, but all of them will have only one term selected.

I need to show a list of the terms that are present on the post and in place of the taxonomy name, I need to show a custom name.

For example:
Taxonomy: Bikes
Term: BTT

Instead of showing something like "Bikes : BTT", I need to show something like "Bicycle : BTT".

I have a code that gives me the taxonomy and the term, but couldn't think of the best way to 'change' that taxonomy for a custom name.

Here is the code so far:

```
//creates the array to format the list of taxonomies
$args = array(
    'template' => __( '%s: %l.' ), 
    'term_template' => '<a href="%1$s">%2$s</a>',
);
//creates the array to receive all the taxonomies
$taxList = get_the_taxonomies( $post->ID, $args );
//shows every taxonomy separately
foreach ($taxList as $taxItem) {
    echo $taxItem;
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can change the label of your taxonomy, as seen on the [Function Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Arguments)

Somewhere in your code, there must be something like

```php
register_taxonomy("bikes", "post", [
  // ...
]);
```

you can change it to

```
register_taxonomy("bikes", "post", [
  "label" => "Bicycle"
]);
```

**PLEASE NOTE** that this part is the definition of the taxonomy itself. Changing it means changing the taxonomy itself and it can affect other parts of your project.

Comment: Can't do that, because I have taxonomies with repeated names, like: Bikes Models, Accessories Models, etc. And they need to look like 'Models'.